# Error in Bigram Text Classification using RTextTools

Tags: r, tm, n-gram, text-classification

I am trying to perform a Bigram text classification using RTextTools. I encounter an error when creating DocumentTermMatrix of Bigrams (shown below). How to fix it?

Sample Dataset:

```
text <- c('sunny','rainy','sunny sunny','sunny rainy','rainy sunny','rainy rainy','sunny sunny sunny','sunny rainy sunny','sunny sunny rainy','rainy sunny sunny','rainy rainy sunny')
issunny <- c('y','n','y','n','n','n','y','y','y','y','n')
data <- data.frame(text,issunny)
```

Libraries Used:

```
library(RTextTools)
library(tm)
```

Code:

```
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(data["text"], ngramLength=2)
container <- create_container(dtMatrix, data$issunny, trainSize=1:nrow(data), virgin=FALSE)
model <- train_model(container, "TREE")
predictionData <- list("sunny sunny sunny rainy rainy", "rainy sunny rainy rainy", "hello", "", "this is another rainy world")
predMatrix <- create_matrix(predictionData, originalMatrix=dtMatrix)
predSize <- length(predictionData)
predictionContainer <- create_container(predMatrix, labels=rep(0,predSize), testSize=1:predSize, virgin=FALSE)
result <- classify_model(predictionContainer, model)
```

Error Encountered:

There is no error when `ngramLength=1`

```
dtMatrix <- create_matrix(data["text"], ngramLength=2);

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-character argument
```

Also Tried Using `RWeka` library but encountered Error:

```
library(RTextTools)
library(tm)
library(RWeka)

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
dtMatrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(data["text"])), control=list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))       

Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(matrix, totalSize, ) : subscript out of bounds
```

**EDIT:**

Replacing data["text"] with as.character(data[, "text"]) in the second code using RWeka package fixed the error encountered in DocumentTermMatrix creation. Thanks a lot to LukeA for his solution.

But now I encounter another Error while creating Prediction Matrix Container:

```
predictionContainer <- create_container(predMatrix, labels=rep(0,predSize), testSize=1:predSize, virgin=FALSE);

Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “matrix.csr” object: ra has too few, or too many elements
```

Comment: The 1st one throws an error here, too. Also with `as.character(data[, "text"])`. Looks like a bug. The 2nd one works fine. Anyway, I'd try `library(quanteda); dfm(as.character(data[, "text"]), ngrams = 2)`. It's a superb text mining package.

Comment: Is all this code necessary? The error occurs at the first line.

Comment: @lukeA Thank you very much. As you mentioned, as.character(data[, "text"] in 2nd one works fine. But now I encounter another error as I shown in the edit part of my question.

Comment: @Pascal The reason I included the entire code is when I was trying a couple of days back, I was able to create a DocumentTermMatrix (couldn't remember how) but got an error at the Prediction Container. I was not able to reproduce that error as I got struck with DocumentTermMatrix creation then.